# Magento 2 - Facebook pixel tracking on AddToCart event

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart, pixel-tracking, facebook-pixel

**Note: Before marking it as duplicate please read description carefully**

I am creating a module for Facebook pixel tracking and I am stuck at `AddToCart` event.

I have seen some 3rd party extensions, but the issue is they are tracking `AddToCart` after page load and my `AddToCart` event should based on ajax based.

So my question is, how can I trigger `AddToCart` facebook pixel code **after ajax add to cart**?

Comment: Are you using the standard magento 2 ajax functionality?

Comment: Yes, most probably standard, I didn't use any plugin for this

Comment: If you know the ID/Class of the add to cart button why not just create a custom on page javascript something like $('.addtocart.btn').on('click', function() { // Do the Magic }); you may need to adjust the class

Comment: I think this should work. I will surely try this. Please add it in answer, I will vote it anyways if it is working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ID/Class of the add to cart button why not just create a custom on page javascript something like

`$('.addtocart.btn').on('click', function() 
 { 
    // Do the Magic 
 });`

you may need to adjust the class. i will create a extension for FB pixel very soon to include the ajax add to cart option. so fixes an issue a lot of people will be having

Comment: worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: hi @Dava, can you look into this issue, and update me please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart-in-magento-2